# PHP odbc_connect - failed to connect to firebird

Tags: php, odbc, firebird

I'm trying to connect to database by ODBC Setup
[Firebird ODBC setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8c2sW.png)

```
<?php
$user = "SYSDBA"; 
$password = "masterkey";
$dsn= "DRIVER={Devart ODBC Driver for Firebird};Database=bazatestowa;Server=localhost;Port=3050"; 
$con=odbc_connect($dsn,$user,$password);
if($con){
  echo "Connected";
  }else{
  echo "Failed";  }
  ?>
```

This is error I get:

> Warning: odbc_connect(): SQL error: [Microsoft][driver manager
> ODBC] Could not find data source name and no default driver specified
> , SQL state IM002 in SQLConnect in
> C:\Integracja-skrypty\index.php on line 5

I have no idea what to input in $dsn to make it work.

---

I translated the error message.

```
<?php
    $user = "SYSDBA"; 
    $password = "masterkey";
    $dsn= "DRIVER={bazatestowa}"; 
    $con=odbc_connect($dsn,$user,$password);
    if($con){
      echo "Connected";
  }else{
      echo "Failed";
  }
      ?>
```

With this code the error is the same.

```
<?php
$user = "SYSDBA"; 
$password = "masterkey";
$dsn= "bazatestowa"; 
$con=odbc_connect($dsn,$user,$password);
if($con){
  echo "Connected";  }else{   echo "Failed";  }

  ?>
```

With this code I have this error

> PHP Warning: odbc_connect (): SQL error: [Microsoft] [ODBC driver
> manager] Given DSN contains architecture mismatch between driver and
> application, SQL state IM014 in SQLConnect in C: \ Integration-scripts
> \ index.php on line 5

Comment: You'll need to translate the error message into English for us

Comment: As far as I know (but I hardly use ODBC, let alone PHP), if you want to use a system DSN like defined in the screenshot, then your connection string should be different than the one you're using. As far as I know if you want to use that system DSN, then your $dsn value should just be `"bazatestowa"`. If you don't want to use the system DSN, then your current DSN doesn't match the details shown in the screenshot.

Comment: As far as I know, the second error happens when you defined the ODBC DNS in the 32-bit ODBC manager, but your application is 64-bit (or vice versa). Make sure you define the DSN in the right ODBC manager (you also need to have a version of the driver with the right bitness).

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error message "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified" is an incorrect ODBC driver name in the connection string. This situation arises when the specified driver is not installed in the system or with errors. In addition, mistakes can be made in any character while specifying the driver's name. To ensure that the driver is correctly installed and to find out its correct name, you can use the ODBC Administrator program.

The reason for the error message "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application" is a mismatch in the bitness of the driver and the application that uses the driver. For example, when running x86 applications that use any ODBC driver, it is necessary to specify a DSN created in the x86 ODBC Administrator.